# Facebook graph api in /act_<account-id>/adcreatives

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The call to /adcreatives edge on adaccount api (/act_<>/) is failing with the following. I was able to narrow it down to a particular creative, which fails when I request object_story_spec field

```
"error_user_title": "First Dof Value Should Match Object Story Spec Field",
```

````
"error_user_msg": "For a Degrees of freedom enabled ad, the first value of Asset Feed Spec field should match the corresponding field in Object Story Spec.", ```


I haven't been able to find any reference to this error code  ("error_subcode": 2446211 ), or the issue anywhere
````

Answer (score -1):

use /me/adaccounts then use fields adcreative to report

Comment: when i use this :
me/adaccounts?fields=adcreatives{name,actor_id,object_type,status,use_page_actor_override,object_story_spec}
i get answer when i make a Ad in Ads Manager  
I have same problem with Adcreative!